# Get-ChildItem & Export-Csv with Path from $_.basename

Tags: powershell

I need to add a patch to a filename when exporting which is generated from the `Get-Childitem`.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\*.txt' | foreach-Object {
*some magic here*
} | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8 ($_.basename + ".txt")
```

Works fine, but now I want to add a path to the resulting txt files.

I changed the code to

```
| export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8 -path "c:\temp\csv_temp\"($_.basename + ".csv")
```

which failed. I also tried:

```
| export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8 ("c:\temp\test\"+ $_.basename + ".txt")
```

also with the same result.

Comment: What error are you getting? the second 'failed' attempt looks just fine:
("c:\temp\test\"+ $_.basename + ".txt")

Comment: Won't help with your issue but `"c:\temp\test\$($_.basename).txt"` can be used as a more readable form of `("c:\temp\test\"+ $_.basename + ".txt")`

Comment: Which object are you trying to read BaseName from? The `Get-ChildItem`-object or the objects you create in the `foreach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The `($_.basename + ".txt")` in your `Export-Csv` call *cannot* work**, because `$_` is not defined when used directly as a parameter value, outside of a *script block*.

(Unless you had explicitly assigned an object with a `.basename` property to `$_` beforehand - which you shouldn't do - `$_` is undefined, so `($_.basename + ".txt")` evaluates to `".txt"`, and you're effectively outputting to a file named `.txt`.)

**You generally cannot use `$_` - or even a variable passed from an earlier pipeline stage with the `-PipelineVariable` / `-pv` common parameter - as a *direct* parameter value, *outside of a script block*.**<sup>[1]</sup>

Therefore, I suggest you **restructure your command** as follows (making use of the [PSv4+ **`-pv`** / **`-PipelineVariable`** common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-pipelinevariable) for convenience, but it's easy to adapt the solution to PSv3-):

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\*.txt' -pv fileObj | ForEach-Object {
  *some magic here* |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8 ($fileObj.basename + ".txt")
}
```

By moving the `Export-Csv` call into the `ForEach-Object` script block, you can make use of the `$fileObj` variable created by `-pv fileObj`, representing the input file at hand.

While the input file is also reflected in `$_` inside the script block, `$_` is *redefined* in the context of the *embedded* pipeline, so `-pv fileObj` is a convenient way to create a variable that refers to the outer pipeline's input object as `$fileObj`; alternatively, you could execute `$fileObj = $_` at the start of the script block, which makes the solution work in PSv3- too.

The alternative target-file-path arguments are then:

```
# Using an expandable string with an *embedded* expression:
# Note the $(...) surrounding the expression
"c:\temp\csv_temp\$($fileObj.basename + ".csv")"

# Using an expression (string concatenation):
("c:\temp\test\" + $fileObj.basename + ".txt")
```

---

<sup>[1] The reason is that directly passed values are bound to their parameter variables *before* any objects are sent through the pipeline.</sup>